# Как создать нейросеть для крестиков ноликов?

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр, искусственный-интеллект

Я пишу крестики нолики для хакатона, используя javafx и задумался, как сделать ии для игры против компьютера, подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать нейросеть? С ии вообще не работал. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Почитайте учебник по нейросетям.

Comment: за 3 часа? Мне прям срочно надо:(

Comment: А не получится. Это все равно, что решать задачу по матану не зная алгебры.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае проще реализовать не большую и сложную ИИ, а простой алгоритм, который по пользовательскому ходу понимает как ему можно помешать. Просто в условиях пропишите логику, по которой играете сами.

Например, если пользователь поставил крестик в углу, то вам надо помешать ему заполнить строку, столбец и диагональ.